# How should questions about a characteristic of multiple launchers be handled?

Tags: discussion

Following up on [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/53727/why-does-the-minotaur-i-wear-a-yellow-jacket-that-banana-peels-off-as-it-launc), I'd like to ask about the temperature requirements for various solid boosters, including but not limited to Shuttle SRBs, SLS SRBs, and the Minotaur I's second stage. I'm not sure if I should ask one question per booster or one question for all boosters, and in the latter case, how I should word it to avoid being too open-ended. How should I proceed?

Comment: FWIW, I could answer a question about the temperature requirements for STS SRBs, but not the others.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I figured as much. Maybe I should make it a community wiki question, with one answer per booster?

Comment: @DylanSp that sounds like an excellent solution to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in comments, what I'll do is ask a single question, making it a community wiki question with one answer per booster.

Comment: Posted https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/53803/what-are-the-temperature-constraints-on-various-solid-rocket-boosters.

Comment: you mean a community Wiki *answer* right? We usually don't make the question post itself a wiki, it's the answer that gets wikified.